# Pyspark code to get all date in dataframe from given start date and end date

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given start_date = "1900-01-01"
end_date = "2022-01-31"

I am expecting the pyspark code to get date dataframe with date populated between the start_date and end_date populated.
Tried the below code but getting error int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Column'

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, date_add, to_date
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DateDataFrame").getOrCreate()

# define start_date and end_date
start_date = "1900-01-01"
end_date = "2022-01-31"


date_df = spark.range(0, (to_date(col(end_date)) - to_date(col(start_date))).cast("int")).select(date_add(to_date(start_date), col("id")).alias("date"))
```

Comment: Referring to the docs (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.alias.html#pyspark.sql.Column.alias), I think the last argument in your last line is a pyspark.sql.column.Column type object and all arguments of the range function are ints I believe (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.range.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`sequence`** function and give your `start` and `end date` with `interval 1 day`.

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.sql("""SELECT sequence(to_date('1900-01-01'), to_date('2022-01-31'), interval 1 day""")
```

---

If you want to have date to be in one column then explode the array as shown below.

```
start_date='1900-01-01'
end_date='2022-01-31'
df = spark.sql(f"select explode(sequence(to_date('{start_date}'), to_date('{end_date}'), interval 1 day))")
df.show(10,False)
#+----------+
#|col       |
#+----------+
#|1900-01-01|
#|1900-01-02|
#|1900-01-03|
#|1900-01-04|
#|1900-01-05|
#|1900-01-06|
#|1900-01-07|
#|1900-01-08|
#|1900-01-09|
#|1900-01-10|
#+----------+
```